# Проверка на уникальность значения в многомерном массиве

Tags: php

Необходимо очистить многомерный массив от дубликатов по значению одного элемента, т.е. из

```
$arr = array (
    '0' => array(
            'key' => 'value',
            'key2' => 'value2',
           ),
    '1' => array(
            'key' => 'value',
            'key2' => 'value3',
           ),
);
```

необходимо получить

```
$arr = array (
        '0' => array(
                'key' => 'value',
                'key2' => 'value2',
               )
    );
```

Пытаюсь так

```
$result = array();

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (!array_search($value['key'], $result)) $result[] = $value;
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '<pre>';
```

подскажите как можно решить эту задачу с минимальной нагрузкой, т.к. элементов для сравнения около 1000 штук

Comment: Если элементов 1000 штук, то не стоит даже задумываться о нагрузке. Судя по всему просто удалять или создавать нормальную копию, результат будет очень близок.

Comment: Идти по массиву foreach и все найденные значения класть в качестве ключей в другой массив. И если ключ уже в том втором массиве есть - то удалять ветку.

Comment: @Mike, ) не могу в голове представить это условие, помогите с кодом

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, обновил вопрос

Comment: От куда береться массив?

Comment: а чем [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) не угодил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr = array ('0' => array('key' => 'value','key2' => 'value2'),
              '1' => array('key' => 'value','key2' => 'value3'),
              '2' => array('key' => 'valueX', 'key2'=>'value4'));

$keys=array(); // Массив ключей, которые уже встречались
foreach($arr as $k=>$val) {
 if(array_key_exists($val['key'],$keys)) {
   unset($arr[$k]);
  } else {
   $keys[$val['key']]=1;
  }
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Алгоритм не создает новый массив и не копирует никуда значения из старого массива, у именно удаляет дубли из исходного массива. Что бы понять, что значение 'key' уже встречалось ранее, заводится рабочий массив `$keys` в котором просто сохраняются значения, которые уже встречались в виде `$keys['value']=1`. Проверка проходит по этому массиву функцией поиска ключа в массиве, она работает гораздо быстрее, чем поиск значения в массиве, т.к. для доступа по ключам PHP использует внутреннюю оптимизацию (хеширование и возможно двоичное дерево поиска, не вдавался в подробности).

Итоговая сложность около O(n), в отличие от алгоритмов ведущих поиск ключей повторным перебором массива, включая встроенные array_search и т.п.

Comment: Ну по-поводу O(n) можно поспорить, т.к. есть `array_key_exists`, но в целом подход действительно хорош.

Comment: попробовал на исходных данных. Мой метод вернул 950 из 970. Ваше решение 970 из 970. Где правда пока не знаю.

Comment: Ну в приведенном коде он удаляет второй элемент из массива. И как бы ломаться тут нечему. Хотя в вашем цикле ошибок так же не заметно

Comment: Возможно array_key_exists не корректно работает с кириллицей

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer проверил кирилицу, в UTF-8, работает

Comment: @Mike, тогда вдвойне странно. Пока оставил свой вариант.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer А вы свой вариант попросите скопировать дубли в отдельный массив и посмотрите на них. потом видя их можно найти похожий элемент в отфильтрованных данных и сделать их них контрольный пример. Что то мне подсказывает у вас проблема связана с чем то другим. например вы заключили мой код в функцию и передачи ей массив по значению, а результат ожидали сам собой. А функция получает копию массива. Если параметр не объявлять как `&$arr`

Comment: @Mike, И правда), ссылку то забыл поставить

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Вот, а беспокоитесь о скорости ... Он же без ссылки в любую функцию отдает ваши 1000 записей копированием ... думаю оптимизацию стоит начать с расстоновки ссылок везде где можно, при работе с такими массивами

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем решилось так:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $match = false;
    for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++) {
        if ($value['key'] === $result[$i]['key']) $match = true;
    }
    if (!$match) $result[] = $value;
}

return $result;
```

Comment: Для оптимизации во внутренний цикл (`for`) можно добавить `break` при нахождении  совпадения.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrays = [[1],[2],[1],[3]];

$new_array = [];

$a = 0;
foreach ($arrays as $array){
  foreach ($array as $i){
    $new_array[$a] = $i;
  }
$a++;
}

var_dump(array_unique($new_array));

/*
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
}
*/
```